# Dynamic Random number glitch

Tags: debugging, random, actionscript-2

For my project, http://www.swfcabin.com/swf-files/1302575829.swf, Sometimes a number doesn't appear when I "scratch" the top part off. This is the code that was being used (yes it's a little nooby, but I'm new at this)

```
{ 
    ZooM = random (20) +1; 
    gotoandplay(2);
}
```

How can I make it so a number appears EVERY time? Thanks!
-Zach

PS: ActionScript2

Comment: Zach, you're going to need to give a bit more info. Where is this code placed, and how do you get the value from `ZooM` into the textfields?

Answer (score 0):

Use the floor method and multiplication:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
```